# Direct limit of automorphism group of cyclic groups of order $p^r$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let ${\rm Aut}((\mathbf{Z}/p^r))$, denote the automorphism group of the cyclic group of order $p^r$. Then $\{ \mathbf{Z}/p^r, i^r\}_{r \in \mathbf{N}}$, with inclusions $i^r : \mathbf{Z}/p^r \to \mathbf{Z}/p^{r+1}$ forms a direct system. Then can we identify (up to isomorphism) the automorphism groups ${\rm Aut}(\mathbf{Z}_{p}) = {\rm colim}_{r \in \mathbf{N}} {\rm Aut}(\mathbf{Z}/p^r)$, where $\mathbf{Z}_p$ denotes the group of $p$-adic integers?

Comment: This would be "too optimistic", see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30572/what-is-the-automorphism-group-of-the-additive-group-of-the-p-adic-integers)?

Comment: @DietrichBurde What is too optimistic ? I find we have the group $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p^\infty}/\mathbb{Z}=\{ \frac{a}{p^r} +\mathbb{Z}\}$ whose endomorphisms are of the form $\frac{a}{p^r} +\mathbb{Z}\to \frac{ab_r}{p^r}+\mathbb{Z}$ with $b_r \in \mathbb{Z}/p^r\mathbb{Z}$ ie. $b\in \mathbb{Z}_p$ and the automorphisms are those with $b_r \in \mathbb{Z}_p^\times$. What I don't understand is why $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p^\infty}/\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_p$ have the same automorphisms.

Comment: There are no more automorpisms of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ than $\mathbb{Z}_p^\times$ because they send $p^r\mathbb{Z}_p$ to subgroups of index $p^r$.

Comment: @reuns actually your second comment is what made me ask the question. I mean it is not apparent to me (could be trivial or not) if the equality in question holds. However, the colimit contains, say strings, whose coordinate-wise behaviour depends on subgroups of order $p^r$. Thus it wouldn't surprise me the above equality.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it works and also for its powers, and endomorphisms: if $M,M'$ are finitely generated $\mathbf{Z}_p$-modules, then writing $M_n=M/p^nM$, we have, denoting by Hom group homomorphisms
$$\mathrm{Hom}(M,M')=\mathrm{Hom}(M,\underleftarrow{\lim}M'_n)=\underleftarrow{\lim}\mathrm{Hom}(M,M'_n)=\underleftarrow{\lim}\mathrm{Hom}(M_n,M'_n).$$
In particular, we have an injective natural map $\underleftarrow{\lim}\mathrm{Aut}(M_n)\to \mathrm{Aut}(M)$, and in the reverse direction a natural monoid homomorphism map $\mathrm{Aut}(M)\to\underleftarrow{\lim}\mathrm{End}(M_n)$; since the composite map into $\mathrm{End}(M_n)$ maps into the subgroup of invertible elements, the previous map maps into $\underleftarrow{\lim}\mathrm{Aut}(M_n)$. So we have a natural isomorphism $\mathrm{Aut}(M)\to\underleftarrow{\lim}\mathrm{Aut}(M_n)$.

---

Let $M$ be an abelian group such that $M=\bigcup M_{(n)}$, where $M_{(n)}$ is the kernel of multiplication by $p^n$. Then the structural ring homomorphism $\mathbf{Z}\to\mathrm{End}(M)$ has a unique extension to $\mathbf{Z}_p$.

Suppose moreover that $M_{(n)}$ is cyclic of order $p^n$ for all $n$. Then the resulting continuous homomorphism $\mathbf{Z}_p\to\mathrm{End}(M)$ is a topological isomorphism. It is continuous and injective on $\mathbf{Z}$; since the only closed subgroups of $\mathbf{Z}_p$ are the $p^n\mathbf{Z}_p$, the kernel is zero. For surjectivity, by compactness, it is enough to check that it has a dense image ($\mathrm{End}(M)$ is endowed with the topology of pointwise convergence). And indeed every finite subset is contained in $M_{(n)}$ for some $n$, and every endomorphism coincides with some integral multiplication on $M_{(n)}$. So the image of $\mathbf{Z}$ in $\mathrm{End}(M)$ is dense.

In particular, the canonical continuous map $\mathbf{Z}_p^\times\to\mathrm{Aut}(M)$ is a topological isomorphism in this case.

Comment: thanks for posting; my initial question was about colimit and not limit. So you assert that ${\rm Aut}(\mathbf{Z}_p)={\rm lim Aut}(\mathbf{Z}/p^r)$, if I understand correctly. What confuses me I the first "Yes," you put at the beginning. Furthermore I just regard the groups just as abelian groups and not a particular type of module.

Comment: I'm explicit about this: I start with $\mathbf{Z}_p$-modules, and I treat them as abelian groups.

Comment: sorry for the nitpicking, my fault.

Comment: But actually here all homomorphisms as abelian groups are homomorphisms as $\mathbf{Z}_p$-modules, a posteriori.

Comment: @user430191 You are asking if $Aut(\frac{\mathbf{Z}}{p^\infty} / \mathbf{Z}) \simeq  \mathbf{Z}_p^\times \simeq Aut(\mathbf{Z}_p)$, right ? ($\frac{\mathbf{Z}}{p^\infty} / \mathbf{Z}$ is the $p$-subgroup of $\mathbf{Q}/\mathbf{Z}$ whose elements are of the form $\frac{a}{p^r}+\mathbf{Z}$, and $Aut(\frac{\mathbf{Z}}{p^\infty} / \mathbf{Z})$ appears naturally as $Gal(\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_{p^\infty})/\mathbf{Q}$) Ycor is showing that $Aut(\mathbf{Z}_p) \simeq \mathbf{Z}_p^\times$.

Comment: It's also true that the natural map $\mathbf{Z}_p^\times\to\mathbf{Aut}(\mathbf{Q}_p/\mathbf{Z}_p)(=\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbf{Z}[1/p]/\mathbf{Z})$) is an isomorphism, restriction of the isomorphism $\mathbf{Z}_p\to\mathrm{End}(\mathbf{Q}_p/\mathbf{Z}_p)$.

Comment: @YCor ... Right that it is $\mathbf{Q}_p/\mathbf{Z}_p$ seems a good argument for why it has the same Aut as $\mathbf{Z}_p$. So in general projective limits and direct limits of the same sequence of groups have no reason to be related by their Aut ?

Comment: @user430191 I also don't really know exactly what you asked...!

Comment: @YCor thanks for the effort you've put on. I learned something from your post anyway :). Though I don't see how it answers my inital question. I simply asked, whether ${\rm Aut}(\mathbf{Z}_p)={\rm colim Aut}(\mathbf{Z}/p^r)$.

Comment: Yes, the first part answers the initial question with $M=\mathbf{Z}_p$.

Comment: @user430191 ... What is ${\rm colim Aut}(\mathbf{Z}/p^r)$ ? (did you mean $ {\rm Aut \ colim}(\mathbf{Z}/p^r)$ ?) Make things explicit, we have two different abelian groups : $\mathbf{Z}_p$ and $\mathbf{Q}_p/\mathbf{Z}_p\simeq \mathbf{Z}[\frac{1}{p}]/\mathbf{Z}= \{ \frac{a}{p^r}+\mathbf{Z}\}$ together with their automorphisms groups.

Comment: The automorphism group of a limit by inclusion ($\rm colim$) is a limit by projection (projection means surjective morphisms). That's why ${\rm Aut \ colim}(\mathbf{Z}/p^r) = {\rm lim proj } ({\rm Aut }(\mathbf{Z}/p^r))={\rm lim proj }\mathbf{Z}/(p^r)^\times= \mathbf{Z}_p^\times$

Comment: @reuns no it's not true in general. For instance, consider Aut of $\mathbf{Z}[1/p]$ viewed as colimit of copies of $\mathbf{Z}$. It's true if you assume that members of the union are characteristic subgroups (as in the present case).

Comment: @user430191 you should better show your efforts to obtain an answer adapted to your level and way of thinking. ${\rm colim Aut}(\mathbf{Z}/p^r) = {\rm colim}(\mathbf{Z}/p^r)^\times$ exists but in the inclusion  $(\mathbf{Z}/p^r)^\times \to (\mathbf{Z}/p^{r+1})^\times, a \mapsto a+h_r(a) p^r$ the functions $h_r : \mathbf{Z}:\mathbf{Z}$ are far from being obvious.